# How can I keep $location.hash() from adding a / right after the #?

Tags: angularjs

When I use $location.hash("section1"), the URL ends up as http://thing/place#/section1. When I use $location.hash("section1") a second time, the URL becomes http://thing/place#/section1#section1. This is rather surprising. (Further uses of $location.hash("section1") act more-or-less as expected, changing the last part of the URL after the second #.)

Context: the page I'm creating is a one-page app in AngularJS where the multiple sections of the page are laid out as templates; there's a top-level controller, and the templates are hidden/shown based on a property called "mode" in the scope of that controller. I'm using $location.hash() in a pretty bare-bones way: when that top-level controller loads, it sets the mode depending on the contents of $location.hash(). (And there's a $watch on the mode that calls $location.hash("modeName") when the mode changes.)

How can I persuade $location.hash() to only add a single # to the URL, so I can use $location.hash() to both set and get the current mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I hadn't set html5 mode in $locationProvider. (I was surprised; I thought that non-html5 mode always had hashbang mode, and when I didn't see the bang in front of the hash I assumed there was something else going on.) As a side note, my watch on $location.hash() also caused an infinite loop (set hash to "#thing", AngularJS sets hash to "#/thing", repeat.), but this was unrelated.

For posterity, the way to set html5 mode on the $location service is to add this to your initialization:

```
Angular.module(....)
    ....controllers, services & squid....
    .config(function ($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```